# Manga about a boy who is sent into a game as a character he created, with four sex skills

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

A few months ago I read a manga about this boy who got sent to this game he was playing, as a game character he created as a joke. As such he had only  4 skills, and they were all sex skills. I think it was sex maniac, will to be protected and handsome.

Comment: What do you mean by "I think it was sex maniac, will to be protected and handsome"...? Are those the skills? Also, can you describe any other characters in the story? In particular, were there any villains or antagonists? And if so, what were they like?

Comment: Maybe "Isekai Kita node Sukebe Skill de Zenryoku Ouka Shiyou to Omou", but it's a hentai comic sans I can't check it out right now.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Net Character Kari Play no Tsumori ga Isekai Shoukan: Mayoibito wa Josei no Teki ni Ninteisaremashita](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/net-character-kari-play-no-tsumori-ga-isekai-shoukan-mayoibito-wa-josei-no-teki-ni-ninteisaremashita) (not exactly safe for work). It's not a straight up hentai comic, but it's close.

> Horikawa Kento, a 35 year old man was transported into a different world with online game skills. His character is a 15 year old boy with absurd skills. "Handsome", "Well-protected", "Womanizer" and "Sexual Prodigy". In order to survive in this world of monsters, how will he use his skills?

The "well-protected" skill seems to be in the sense of "girls want to protect him". The handsome and sexual prodigy are self-explanatory and basically the same as what's in the question.